# HTML Parsing - Source File Export Issue - Chrome

Tags: java, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to retrieve table data from saved html code, but am having an issue with the file itself. When opened with chrome, the source code displays as one would expect, headers and organized html tags separated by new lines. I will post some examples below. However when opening the program from textedit or loading it into my parsing program the file is altered in structure and content. Not only is the file unorganized, the data do not show up in the code.

The header as opened in Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info=
```

The table data as shown in Chrome:

```
<tr style="background-color:transparent;" class="order-row" orderid="1022478">
<td style="text-align:center;">
<a href="https://mrdelivery.com/admin/orders/1022478/dispatcher" style="font-size:20px;font-family:monospace;">1022478</a>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center;"><div title="B-Town Diner" style="cursor:pointer; display:block; color:#006633; background:#F2F2F2; padding:0.1em 0.5em; margin:0.1em 0; border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); font-weight:bold;" id="twilio-block-1022478-1094"><span onclick="choose_status_for(1022478,1094);">CONFIRMED<br/><span style="font-size:10px;">9m21s</span></span><div class="dropdown"></div></div> </td>
<td style="text-align:center;">N </td>
<td style="text-align:center;">Bloomington,IN</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">Delivered</td>

<td style="text-align:center;"><a href="https://mrdelivery.com/admin/orders/1022478/dispatcher" style="display:block;font-size:18px;outline:1px solid transparent;background-color:transparent;color:;">0h&nbsp;38m</a></td>
<td style="text-align:center;font-size:14px;font-weight:bolder;">
Jackson B.
</td>
```

Table header when opened in textedit or java.util.Scanner: 
(Note: printed as individual tokens)

```
<!--
saved
from
url=(0054)file://localhost/Users/jordanlandgrebe/Desktop/AUG.htm
-->
<html><head><meta
http-equiv="Content-Type"
content="text/html;
charset=UTF-8"></head><body><div
class="line-gutter-backdrop"></div><table><tbody><tr><td
class="line-number"
value="1"></td><td
class="line-content"><span
class="html-doctype">&lt;!DOCTYPE
html&gt;</span></td></tr><tr><td
class="line-number"
value="2"></td><td
class="line-content"><span
class="html-tag">&lt;html&gt;</span></td></tr><tr><td
class="line-number"
value="3"></td><td
class="line-content">
<span
class="html-tag">&lt;head&gt;</span></td></tr><tr><td
class="line-number"
value="4"></td><td
class="line-content">
<span
class="html-tag">&lt;meta
<span
```

I think the issue may be something with how Chrome saves webpages/source code that I am unaware of. Searching I have been unable to find anything about exporting html from chrome as plain text. I also am unable to use any extensions that might pull the tables from the live page as I only have the source code to work with.

Is there a way to get what the file displays in Chrome saved as a plain text file with the same content and format? -Aside from writing my own extension to print out line by line what I am viewing already.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Save a table from a web page?  Is this an automated task or semi-automated task?  If using Chrome you should still be able to execute script against a static, offline document (provided its a valid DOM)

Comment: It's also not clear whether this is a programming question or an off-topic program-usage question suitable for http://superuser.com but not stackoverflow. I'm inclined to think it's the latter. BTW the answer might be to use `Ctrl-S` right on the page instead of `Ctrl-U` + `Ctrl-S`.

Comment: I'm trying to save a rather large table from the webpage. It's an automated task - the program I wrote just parses the document and spits out a csv. You're saying I could try using an export extension on the file saved locally?

Comment: You may be right wOxxOm - I could go that route as I was unware of superuser.com until you metioned it.

Ctrl + S results in the same issues.

Comment: Try opening devtools (F12 key) -> Elements panel -> rightclick `HTML` element -> Copy outer html -> paste into a notepad -> save the file.